# Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#

How should i handle this error in my code? I tried changing List to List but there will be error at this statement :

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff);
```

Shown below is part of the code that I'm doing..

```
List<string[]> dataCollection = new List<string[]>();
List<string> timeCollection = new List<string>();
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff");

        if (x == unit && count == 3)  
        {
            dataCollection.Add(ReceivedData); 
            timeCollection.Add(time);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataCollection.Count(); i++)  //write out all the data lines
            {
                string[] dataArray = dataCollection[i];
                string dataOutput = "";

                for (int j = 0; j < dataArray.Length; j++)
                {
                    dataOutput += dataArray[j] +" ";  //Link all data to write out
                }
            for (int k = 4; k > timeCollection.Count(); k--)
            {
                string[] timeArray = timeCollection[k];  //error for timeCollection[k]
                string timeOutput = "";

                for (int t = 0; t < timeArray.Length; t++)
                {
                    timeOutput += timeArray[t];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just as the error message says: `timeCollection[k]` returns a String. On the other hand, `dataCollection[k]` returns a String[].

Comment: @user2864740 right... so i should modify it so that timeCollection[k] would returns a string[] too..

Comment: If and only if that is what is desired.. as then String[] objects have to be put in here. Where do they come from? Why? How are they to be used? (Are they even supposed to arrays of strings?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `timeCollection` is a list of strings, so when you access an element of the list (`timeCollection[k]`) you are returning a `string`, yet you are trying to assign it to an array.

```
string[] timeArray = timeCollection[k];
```

Try this instead:

```
string timeValue = timeCollection[k]
```

Or you might need to modify `timeCollection` so that it is a list of string arrays, but that doesn't seem to be the case because the variable `time` is just a string and not an array.

It also seems to me that your two `for` loops could be replaced by these lines:

```
string dataOutput = String.Join(" ", dataCollection.SelectMany(x => x));
string timeOutput = String.Join("", timeCollection.Take(4).Reverse());
```